# How can I change icon of the custom stock-tool button on click event?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/xmcukzyb/8/) where I have two custom [stock-tools](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools) annotations added with `circle` and `rectangle` icons and the pre-defined highchart button for `toggleAnnotations`.

```
stockTools: {
  gui: {
    enabled: true,
    buttons: ['oneAnnotation', 'twoAnnotation', 'toggleAnnotations'],
    definitions: {
      oneAnnotation: {
        className: 'highcharts-one-annotation',
        symbol: 'circle.svg'
      },
      twoAnnotation: {
        className: 'highcharts-two-annotation',
        symbol: 'rectangle.svg'
      },
    }
  }
},
```

As we can see, in this pre-defined button that toggles visibility of the annotations, the icon changes on the button click. So I want to have the very same thing in my custom buttons. I actually need one custom button (not two as in the example above) and I want to change its icon when the user will click on it. So I would like to switch between the `circle.svg` and `rectangle.svg` icons.

Clicks over the buttons are managed with the part:

```
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    oneAnnotation: {
      className: 'highcharts-one-annotation',
      init: function(e) {
        alert("click on the circle annotation");
      }
    },
    twoAnnotation: {
      className: 'highcharts-two-annotation',
      init: function(e) {
        alert("click on the rectangle annotation");
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle `backgroundImage` style of the button element, for example:

```
navigation: {
  bindings: {
    oneAnnotation: {
      className: 'highcharts-one-annotation',
      init: function(button) {
        var iconsURL = 'https://code.highcharts.com/8.2.2/gfx/stock-icons/';
        var url1 = 'url("' + iconsURL + 'rectangle.svg' + '")';
        var url2 = 'url("' + iconsURL + 'circle.svg' + '")';
        var btnStyle = button.children[0].style;

        btnStyle.backgroundImage = btnStyle.backgroundImage === url1 ? url2 : url1;
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahd74kqn/